# Image Selection for Training Visual Recognition

Tags: tensorflow, image-recognition, visual-recognition, watson

I am training a classifier for recognizing certain objects in an image. I am using the Watson Visual Recognition API but I would assume that the same question applies to other recognition APIs as well.

I've collected 400 pictures of something - e.g. dogs.

Before I train Watson, I can delete pictures that may throw things off. Should I delete pictures of:

1. Multiple dogs
2. A dog with another animal
3. A dog with a person
4. A partially obscured dog
5. A dog wearing glasses

Also, would dogs on a white background make for better training samples?

Watson also takes negative examples. Would cats and other small animals be good negative examples? What else?

Answer (score 5):

You are right that this is a general issue for all kinds of custom classifiers and recognizers - be it **[vize.it](http://vize.it/)**, **[clarifai](http://clarif.ai/)**, **[IBM Watson](http://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/visual-recognition.html)**, or [training a neural network on your own say in caffe](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/wiki/Model-Zoo). (Sorted by the number of example images you need to use.)

The important thing you need to ask is **how are you going to use the classifier**? What are the real images you will feed the machine to predict the objects shown? As a general rule, **your training images should be as similar to predict-time images as possible** - both in what they depict (kinds and variety of objects) and how they depict it (e.g. backgrounds). Neural networks are super-powerful and if you feed them enough images, they will learn even the hard cases.

Maybe you want to find dog images in *user's folders* - which will include family photos, screenshots and document scans.  Reflect that variety in the training set.  Ask the user if a dog with another animal should be tagged as a dog photo.

Maybe you want to find dog images on *a wilderness photo trap*. Just use various images taken by that photo trap (or several photo traps, if it's a whole network).

In short — tailor your sample images to the task at hand!